# Github Actions cant not restore nuget from my other repositories starting yesterday

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I have configured github actions to do a nuget restore and it works well until yesterday.

Here are the runs:

https://github.com/ApmeM/godot-fruitlines/actions/runs/3391788708

In top right corner there is a drop down with 2 attempts for the same commit (so it means no repository or workflow changes). The attempt 3 days ago works well, and the attempt yesterday is failing.

Also in my workflow I use GITHUB_TOKEN which actually I do not know if possible to configure. Anyway, I do not remember I did any settings changes and all referenced repositories are mine and public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in security key configuration that was introduced a while ago but I did not use it. It seems it becomes mandatory and after adding permissions section it starts working:

permissions:
contents: read
pages: write
id-token: write
packages: write